# How to select a drain rack for pots and pans?

Tags: equipment, cleaning, pan, pot

I use a dish rack for air drying pots and pans. Unfortunately all of the dish racks I have ever purchased do not stand up to the abuse of pots and pans. Eventually the dish rack begins to break down or doesn't effectively drain water drips because the weight of the pots and pans is not equivalent to that of dishes.

How do I go about selecting a drain rack which will hold up to pots and pans?

Comment: If you hang them from a rail, you don't have to use up space with a rack.

Comment: @rumtscho I guess I am unsure of what you mean by a "rail"

Comment: I mean this thing: http://www.ikea.com/de/de/catalog/products/30072646

Answer (score 3):

Go to a restaurant supply store and get a dish machine rack. They're ugly, but they're built to take a beating.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: buy some heavy-duty cooling racks.  We use these for our pots and pans, and they hold up well.